# Search for a String in each Objects of NSmutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I have `NSmutableArray` with 10,000 NSobjects,  each NSobject has Name, Details and Location.

I want to Create a method which will search for A text in the Names, Details, and Locations of All Objects.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use NSPredicates for this. It's fast and doesn't require much work. Check out this blog post for implementation details: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/03/filtering-fun-with-predicates/

Comment: It's generally preferable to summarize at least enough that the answer would be useful if that blog disappeared one day (which, I mean, I know that would *never* happen, but work with me here).